# How to access data from database to android phonegap calendar

Tags: android, cordova

If i want to get data from my database (as for example of appointment ) to the calendar in `>android phonegap`, how can I view the calendar and access the data from database?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [Android Calendar plugin](https://github.com/tenforwardconsulting/Phonegap-Calendar-Plugin-android) for that. Just make a call to your database to get the data then populate the plugin API fields with your database data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync to iOS as well, you could use this cross-platform version (compatible with PhoneGap Build): https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin